# Quitting a loop

Tags: ruby, fibonacci

My `for` loop produces Fibonacci sequence. I want my `for` loop to stop when it reaches anything past `4000000`. Here's what I have:

```
    x = [1,2]
    for i in 0..40
        y = x[i+1] + x[i]
        x.push(y)
        break if y > 4000000
    end
```

This returns the following

> [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887]

I don't want that last item in my array. Is there anyway to do this simpler than  removing the last item from the array? Also, is there anything inefficient or messy about my code?

Comment: ... swap the last two lines in the loop...

Comment: im such a dope. that makes sense thanks Kevin.

Comment: You should rewrite this as a `while` loop... `while y < 400000`

Comment: I think aside removing last item (that was answered by Kevin), you should post it in: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You shouldn't use for loops in ruby it pisses people off lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the element at last, which will ensure that elements which is getting inserted is within the range

```
x = [1,2]
for i in 0..40
   y = x[i+1] + x[i]
   break if (y > 4000000)
   x.push(y)
end
p x
```

Comment: So just as @user2801122 said three days ago